Photography and drawing, its prohibited. Indulging in it, is it haram
Recently I have been going through various questions on drawing and photography in Islam SE.
I have concluded that drawing and photography of animate objects is definitely haram. Just in cases very necessary, it is fine to photograph.
Now, we come across various paintings and photographs in newspapers, childrens drawings almost on a daily basis.The pictures of leaders shaking hands, or war-ridden captives meeting after long time, or depressing pictures of refugees are seen in newspapers.
Now in calamitous situations, is it necessary to print pictures of the situation that is occurring in the country, or is it not, as their plight can be expressed in words. Yet they provide images to validate their claims and show the seriousness of the situation.
Now, do I indulge myself in the prohibited act of photography, by looking at these pictures, as my intention is to get news from across the world**, and newspapers are a fine tool to achieve this purpose.
My question may not be clear, please provide edit suggestions, I will review it inshallah.
